# How can I create dynamic pages? Javascript or ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, html

HTML5 and Javascript is able to create really good dynamic pages. Is asp.net still usefull if I am a good HTML5 and Javascript designer? Why should I chosse one or the other?

Comment: I hope you are aware that search engines can't run javascript

Comment: Google bot is capable to execute javascript in a limited way. More info here http://www.seroundtable.com/google-ajax-execute-15169.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.net is for server side. Needed if you want to interact with databases and server side logic (eg: session handling, database operations, user authentication etc).

HTML 5 and Javascript is for client side for page rendering and client side logic.

Both target diffrent areas.